# Attach InfoPath to AppWeb Library in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, provider-hosted-app, form-library

Error while adding InfoPath form to form Library created using SharePoint Hosted App which will be deployed to AppWeb.

`This form template is browser-compatible, but it cannot be browser-enabled on the selected site` message

I have Checked in following 3 ways as per suggestion found in Internet.They are

1. Go to Site Collection Feature -> Activate `SharePoint Server Enterprise Site Collection features`.
2. Go to SharePoint Admin Center -> InfoPath -> Allow users to browser-enable form templates checked
3. Go to Library Setting -> Advance Setting -> in Default Open Behaviour for Browser Enabled Template -> the radio button selected is for `Use the server default (Open in the browser)`.

But still the InfoPath is dispalying error